# Uncaught TypeError: trigger_up is not a function (Odoo 17)

Tags: javascript, odoo, odoo-14, odoo-17

I am trying to upgrade an Odoo module from v14 to v17 and I am getting the error "trigger_up is not a function".

```
// the code below is inside: 
// export class OpenStreetMap extends Component {

marker.on("dragend", function (e) {
            var latlng = e.target._latlng;
            self.trigger_up("field_changed", {
              dataPointID: self.dataPointID,
              changes: {
                lat: latlng.lat,
                lng: latlng.lng,
              },
              viewType: self.viewType,
            });
```

I looked into the built-in odoo addons and the trigger_up function does exist. I am guessing that the "field_changed" is the one causing the issue here.

the 'latlng' variable also seems to be working correctly, printing both coordinates in the console when I move the marker.